# SonarQube 5.1.1 "Unable to set search root context for components"

Tags: sonarqube5.1

I've recently upgraded to SonarQube 5.1.1 from 3.7.4. The upgrade appeared to go well.  When I navigate to the home page, I see the projects that existed before.  I navigate to a particular project and see its issues.  However, when I drilldown, say to the Major issues, and click on a source file link, I receive the following message instead of any marked up source code:

"Unable to set search root context for components"

SonarQube is running on linux with jdk1.7.0_09.  The database is Oracle 11g. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: How did you solve this? Does a new analysis fix this? I have the same thing with this setup: upgrade Sonar 3.3.2 to 5.1.2, Windows x64, IBM's Java 7, SQL Server db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is problem is "normal". In fact, in 5.0 release notes, you can see this

---

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+5.0+Upgrade+Notes

Noteworthy
    After the migration, source syntax-highlighting won't be available on a project until it has been successfully analyzed

---

In tried to launch analyze from a new project, and i saw source code ! So, now, i've to launch analyse for all projects :\